# WordPress WooCommerce shop page template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to edit the layout of the shop page of my WooCommerce WordPress webshop.

Now in the WooCommerce settings I set it to disaply the categories. Now my goals is to change the `<img />` tags into `<div>`'s. So I need to change the HTML. But I can't seem to find the template file that is used to create that page. I've looked in my theme folder and in the WooCommerce plugin folder.

Does anyone know where I can find the file or how to change the html output?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I am sorry I think I am just stupid but it doesn't work for me I try `$output .= "<div class='category-div' style='background-image: url('".$cat_image_src."'); width: 100px; height: 300px;'></div>";` but it doesn't work

Comment: @LoicTheAztec and now all the pictures of my products are not being shown

Comment: I have 2 days experience with WordPress/Woocommerce... I just don't understand why I can't find where the html is being rendered to output that specific html. Thanks for your help anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

Check in this folder: `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/woocommerce/archive-product.php`
If your theme is missing the woocommerce folder, then you can create on and past all (or only those you need to edit) template files and folders from `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` to the  `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/woocommerce/`

Also it is a good practice to use [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) when you need to edit the theme of your site so you won't loose your edits when updating it.

Hope this would help.

Comment: hello friend, I tried editing the archive-product.php template file but I can't find the html elements that i wanna change in that file. Which is basically my goal

Comment: aha, I see, you might need to check content-product.php. By the way what text editor do you use. There should be a ways to open a folder and do a search across all its files.

Comment: Do you have anything meaningful in content-product_cat.php?

Comment: I am not sure. I opened the file from inside the woocommerce plugin and there's a bunch of stuff in it

Comment: Ок, so far i have search the woocommerce file to see what I can find and unfortunately the things i have discovered are not good. But before we go further one question: Do you just need to make the pictures of the categories all the same size?

Comment: yeah that's basically the goal. I wanna use a div with a fixed width and heigh and set a bg image so I can set it to cover because the images are all different dimensions

Comment: Sorry, i could not find anything that points me how to solve this problem. May be it is a good idea to make all category pictures the same size so when their thumbnails are generated you will have them in the same sizes as well.
Else you can check for a function in woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php that is called woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail i thing that this is what you need to edit, but remember  - this is a core file, once the plugin is updated you will loose changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Considering this..

> I wanna use a div with a fixed width and heigh and set a bg image so
>   I can set it to cover because the images are all different dimensions

Try this, maybe will work. This will wrap the image with a div. Copy and paste it on functions.php of your theme.

```
// Add the img wrap
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', create_function('', 'echo "<div class=\"img-wrap\">";'), 5, 2);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',create_function('', 'echo "</div>";'), 12, 2);
```